# Lists and pagination authorization in GraphQL business layer

Tags: pagination, authorization, graphql

In Dan Schafer's excellent ["GraphQL at Facebook" talk from React Europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etax3aEe2dA) he goes over how centralizing authorization in business layer models avoids the problem of having to duplicate authorization logic for every edge that leads to an authorized node.

[image: Three layer]

This works fine for something like `Todo.getById(1)` which in my case eventually ends up querying a database for `SELECT * from todos WHERE id=1` and then verifying authorization with `checkCanSee(resultFromDatabase)`.

However, let's say my `todos` table now contains 100,000 todos from multiple users, performing authorization purely in the business layer becomes impractical as I'd need to fetch every todo, filter the result using the shared authorization logic and then slicing that to perform pagination.

Am I wrong thinking that the only way to solve this is by letting authorization logic reside in the persistence layer itself?

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the takeaways from Dan’s talk is the difference in how authorization is handled with GraphQL, as opposed to a typical REST endpoint.

In REST, each resource is typically associated with a single endpoint. When a request is made to that endpoint, it makes sense to check whether the requestor is authorized before processing the request. With GraphQL we may be fetching multiple resources within the same request, so this behavior is no longer desirable. As Dan puts it:

> We don’t want to completely blow up the request if you can’t see one of [the requested resources].

So the preferred approach with GraphQL is to implement some kind of ***per-node*** mechanism for authorization, and to only return the resources the requester is authorized to see. And that is exactly what the example in the talk shows – one way of doing that.

If you store your to-dos in a SQL database table, it would make perfect sense for your code to just make a query like `SELECT * from todos WHERE creator_id=${viewer.id}` and omit using a function like `checkCanSee` altogether.

Similarly, you can bake pagination right into your query with limit-offset, cursors, etc. And yes, since you’re now letting your DB do the heavy lifting, you could say that we’ve moved into the persistence layer. However, it’s still up to your business logic to take the request, sanitize the inputs, construct an appropriate query and return the results in a form GraphQL can use.

I can’t speak for Dan, but I imagine his intent was not to suggest this was the only (or even optimal) way to implement authorization for a node. I think the bigger point is that if you are, for example, fetching:

```
{
  header
  todos  {
    description
  }
  quoteOfTheDay
}
```

even an unauthorized client should still get a response back from the server that it can then use to render a page for the end-user (even if that response includes an empty array of to-dos).

Comment: I'm still convinced letting authorization logic reside in the storage layer is suboptimal. How would you e.g implement a caching between your business logic and the storage layer when authorization is done behind your cache? In addition, what if I decide to use an SQL connector for some fields and another backend system for other fields. I'd have to implement authorization for both the backing systems.

Comment: The purpose of GraphQL is to have a 'singe source of truth'. That means what you want to do is not really allowed explicitly. You will have to make all your backends work with GraphQL to maintain the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

After another round of searching for answers I stumbled upon a few interesting comments from Lee Byron that shed some light on the subject:

- [Let's talk about caching in GraphQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/923#issuecomment-309950002)
- [Over fetching data on the server](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/623#issuecomment-266851309)

The storage layer shouldn't deal with authorization, but it should expose APIs that limit the amount 
of data that's being returned.

In the above scenario dealing with hundreds of thousands of todos this could be implemented by exposing something
like `getTodosByUserId` which returns all todos beloning to a particular user. The business logic layer
would then deal with both authorization and pagination by filtering a slicing the result. But what if 
a user has thousands of todos? One would probably add another filter option to the storage layer
such as `getTodosByUserId({ userId: 1, completed: false })`.

An important take-away from the "Let's talk about caching" comment by Lee is that results
from the storage layer should be easily cachable in something like Redis or memcached. Fetching
a thousand todos from Redis and then filtering and slicing them in your business logic layer is probably
a lot less expensive than having to query an SQL database for every request.

Comment: I'd put it this way: even though many people like Single Responsibility Principle it is impractical to pretend that API design and authorization logic are actually independent. For example, if your regular user is only allowed to see its own todos then it doesn't make sense to use global `todos` node. It should rather be `viewer { todos { ... } }`. So the authorization is not the driver of your API. Its just a safety measure that typically should not fail (just like exceptions are for exceptional cases and not for the typical execution flow). Global `todos` node would check `isAdmin` just once

Answer (score 0):

You can query based on authorization results. In your Todo example:

1. Ask the authorization server whose todos you're allowed to see,
2. `SELECT * FROM todos WHERE owner IN [<permitted owners]]`

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL does not exactly suggest how you should use it. For Facebook, you have to understand they respect many policies thus their decision to keep GraphQL on top of the business layer (and it still makes sense otherwise). To solve the problem you mention, they have implemented caching as well as async processing. This way, they collate and cache your data requests making it easier to retrieve previously queried items.

In your case, you could decide to add the GraphQL above your storage layer if you have no need for a business layer.

GraphQL should be seen as a design pattern for APIs. It is helpful to ensure there is a data retrieval standard (aka. single source of truth) for data/entity models as well as make data authentication and API integration process easier for large systems.